# AngularJS: spyOn both $timeout and $timeout.cancel

Tags: angularjs, timeout, jasmine

When testing part of an AngularJS Application which uses both `$timeout` and `$timeout.cancel` with Jasmine's `spyOn` method.

```
describe('<whatever>', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(this, '$timeout').andCallThrough();
    spyOn(this.$timeout, 'cancel').andCallThrough();
    this.createController();
  });

  it('should <whatever>', function() {
    expect(this.$timeout).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(this.$timeout.cancel).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

You should encounter the following error in your application code, which is using what your test injected into it.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise)');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to run `console.log(Object.keys(this.$timeout));` in your test suite, you will see the following output;

```
LOG: ['identity', 'isSpy', 'plan', 'mostRecentCall', 'argsForCall', 'calls', 'andCallThrough', 'andReturn', 'andThrow', 'andCallFake', 'reset', 'wasCalled', 'callCount', 'baseObj', 'methodName', 'originalValue']
```

`$timeout` is a function which AngularJS is also decorating—since functions are objects—with a `cancel` method. Because this isn't that common a thing to do, Jasmine replaces rather than augments `$timeout` with it's spying implementation - clobbering `$timeout.cancel`.

A workaround for this is to put the `cancel` spy back again after `$timeout` has been overwritten by Jasmine's `$timeout` spy, as follows;

```
describe('<whatever>', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(this.$timeout, 'cancel').andCallThrough();
    var $timeout_cancel = this.$timeout.cancel;
    spyOn(this, '$timeout').andCallThrough();
    this.$timeout.cancel = $timeout_cancel;
    this.createController();
  });

  it('should <whatever>', function() {
    expect(this.$timeout).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(this.$timeout.cancel).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't understand why $timeout is on "this".  I see nothing that assigns it there

Comment: 'this' is the jasmine suite's context, but you can also achieve the same using vars in outer variable scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for $interval, so it should work for $timeout. (jasmine 2)

`var $intervalSpy = jasmine.createSpy('$interval', $interval).and.callThrough();`

Then I can do both:

```
expect($intervalSpy.cancel).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect($intervalSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```